# In AMPHP Parallel, is there a way to get all the tasks which succeeded before a TimeoutCancellation (try catch block task)?

Tags: php, parallel-processing, amphp

I've been working on parallelising some data pipelines with AMPHP in a large codebase, and now I'd like to allow a timeout for if one of the pipelines fails.

The exact behaviour I'm after is having a per-task timeout of 120 seconds and being able to pick up the results of all of the successful tasks, whilst recording failures.

A rough sketch of the code is:

```php
// Turn an async instance (data pipeline method) to a future using an AMPParallelTask wrapper.
$toFuture = fn(Asynchronous $instance) => submit(new AMPParallelTask($instance, $securableId, $securableType, $accountId),
 new TimeoutCancellation(0.1)
        )->getFuture();
[$errors, $responses] = awaitAll(
    array_map($toFuture, $asynchronousInstances)
)
```

The issue is that it's possible for the Tasks' `Task::run` method to contain logic with `try {} catch (Exception $e) {}` blocks in them. When I run the above code, the cancellation of the task throws a CancellationException, which is caught by any try catch which doesn't specialise to a specific kind of exception. If there's a slow task in the try, this can completely break the logic and give incorrect results.

I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish what I want without dropping all `try {} catch (Exception $e) {}` blocks in the `run` logic? My intuition is that maybe I can use channels...?